# Creating a list within an specific class/id / jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, var

I've been using SO for quite a while to get the answers I need, but with this one I hit the wall. I have this in my HTML

```
<div id="items">
    <p id="howto">Add your shopping items below. Click "Add" or hit Enter</p>
    <input type="text" id="additem" name="additem" placeholder="Let's shop!">
    <button id="button">Add</button>
    <ul id="add">
        <li>Click to show it is done (it will move last)</li>
        <li>Double-click to delete</li>
        <li>Happy Shopping!</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="last">
    <ul id="done">
        <li>Item done here</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this on jQuery:

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){
    var item = $("#additem").val();
    var list = "<li>" + item + "</li>";
    $("ul").prepend(list);
    $("#additem").val ("");
});

$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which==13) {
        $("#button").click();
    }
});

$("ul").on("click", "li", function(){
    $(this).append($("#done"));
});

$("ul").on("dblclick", "li", function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

The idea: add an item. When the item is clicked once, it will move to the #done ul. Problem: my var list adds an item as an li, but it will also populate the li inside #done (where only the items checked should be). My beginner logic is that if I make a mistake in clicking an item, I can easily retrieve it from the #done ul back into #add ul (if this doesn't make much sense, hopefully this will: http://jsfiddle.net/mcastillo/AW2Dh/1/). I truly looked for this, but could not find the answer.

Thanks!

Edit: I know I should target the list elements in the var list, however this is where I am stuck (or perhaps there's an easier way to do it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change:

```
$('ul').prepend(list);
```

To:

```
$('#add').prepend(list);
```

The selector `$('ul')` will find all `<ul>` elements on the page and, depending on the jQuery commands, apply to all of them or just the first one found. For example, `prepend`, `append` and `wrap` will be applied to all but `html` will only be applied to the first one found.

Comment: Thanks! I should've paid more attention to details... Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have the append method the wrong way around, it should be:

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function(){
    $("#done").append($(this));
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AW2Dh/2/)